# how to break loop in webpack hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm working with a project nuxt.js, I need to run a shell script on every changed file, that is, every webpack build.

so I'm using the [Webpack Hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/)

I created my [Webpack Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/)

`/plugins/NamedExports.js`

```
const pluginName = 'NamedExports'
const { exec } = require('child_process')

class NamedExports {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tap(pluginName, (params, callback) => {
      exec('sh plugins/shell.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout)
        console.log(stderr)
      })
    })
  }
}

export default NamedExports
```

`plugins/shell.js`

```
parameters=$(ls components)
for item in ${parameters[*]}
do
    ls components/$item/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export { default as \1 } from "./&"#' > components/$item/index.js
done

echo "worked"
```

this script is to make named exports within each folder in the component directory, example

`components/atoms/ButtonStyled.vue`
`components/atoms/BoxStyled.vue`

then it is generated `components/atoms/index.js`

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from "./ButtonStyled.vue"
export { default as BoxStyled } from "./BoxStyled.vue"
```

I registered my Plugin in `nuxt.config.nuxt` or `webpack.config.js`

```
import NamedExports from './plugins/NamedExports.js'

export default {
  // ... other config here ...
  build: {
    plugins: [
      // ... other plugins here ...
      new NamedExports()
    ],
  }
}
```

but when I run my app and change any file, the server says that a change has been made to `components/atoms/index.js` and then a new build is done, so it gets infinite build.

Can someone help me break this loop?

for when to change a file, simply generate new index.js and not generate infinite builds

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a library and solved my problems, below is the link:

### [Weback Plugin - named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously new files retriggering a build. Conceptually, there are a few ways of going about this.

1) if the files are updated, don't output new files. You need to compare timestamps for this. It's probably going to be messy.

2) write a loader. Match `components/**/index.js`, output the correct javascript for it. Ensure **stateless**. I.e. Don't output another file, just a string.

Then put dummy files in each directory with a comment that it's auto-generated by a webpack plugin.

Even better if your dummy file tells webpack how to generate it.

https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/